# How to choose only consecutive numbers from a list using python

Tags: python

I did research and tried the code below. It almost works but I only want the consecutive numbers in the result. That would be [100,101,102]. I do not want the [75], [78], [109] in the result.

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby
data = [75, 78, 100, 101, 102, 109]
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(data), lambda (i,x):i-x):
    print map(itemgetter(1), g)
```

The print out from above is:
[75]

[78]

[100, 101, 102]

[109]

What can I do to just get [100, 101, 102]?

Comment: If the first number were `77` instead of `75`, would you want it too?

Comment: `filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)`?

Comment: Maybe `cons = map(itemgetter(1), g)` and then `if len(cons) > 1: print cons`

Comment: Couldn't you use **yield** and look at preceding value?

Comment: Yes if first number was 77, then I would want it also. Thanks for your suggestions, I haven't tried them yet. I will keep them for reference for now since the answer below works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`g` in your example is the iterable of elements (e.g., [75], or [100, 101, 102]).  If you only want consecutive number**s**, it sounds like you're looking to print all `g`s where there are greater than one elements in `g` [Note, `g` is actually an iterable, but we can quickly convert it to a list with `list()` for a trivial amount of elements.  We'll just need to save the contents, because an element can't be read *twice* from an iterator]

Try wrapping the `print map(itemgetter(1), g)` in an if statement, such as:

```
x = list(g)
if len(x) > 1:
    print map(itemgetter(1), x)
```

Comment: This works. Thank you very much.                                                                   from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby
data = [75,78,100,101,102,103,109]
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(data), lambda (i,x):i-x):
        x = list(g)
        if len(x) > 1:
            print map(itemgetter(1), x)